# Data is not inserted in sql

Tags: php, html

Data is not inserted in sql

When the password are not equal password are not equal is working. However when the password match no data is being updated in my sql. 
Had already tried to import data to sql directly from the database and also confirmed that connection to the database is done.

```
<?php

       $host= 'localhost';
       $user= 'root';
       $pass= '';
       $db= 'newusers';

       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $surname = $_POST['surname'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];


       $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
        if($con)
                /*echo 'Connected Successfully to newusers database';*/

        //if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            //check passwords are equal

            if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmpassword']){
                echo 'Passwords are not equal';
            }
            if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO signup (Name, Surname, Email, Password) values ('$name', '$surname', '$email', '$password')";
        }

?>
```

The expected result is that if the passwords are equal the data will be uploaded to mysql

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You're not executing the query. You've only written it.

Comment: You should not use the root user for your application. Your root user should have a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code. First, you do not have curly brackets in the right places to make sure your comparisons are in context. You should have curly brackets surrounding your connect check:

```
if($con) {
   // your code here
}
```

Fixing that, you then need to execute your query. One way of doing it is with `mysqli_query()`:

```
$host= 'localhost';
$user= 'root';
$pass= '';
$db= 'newusers';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if($con) { // added opening bracket here

    /*echo 'Connected Successfully to newusers database';*/

    //if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        //check passwords are equal
    //} added closing bracket here 

    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmpassword']){
        echo 'Passwords are not equal';
    } else { // you don't need another 'if' statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO signup (Name, Surname, Email, Password) values ('$name', '$surname', '$email', '$password')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); // execute the query
    }
}
```

### WARNING!

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

**Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

### Always check for errors!

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback it works fine now :) 
with regards to SQL injection attack it is noted